# Microsoft Graph API - Getting License Assignment Details

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm noticing that when querying the Beta version of the Microsoft Graph API using `GET http://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users` that the JSON payload returned from the request contains license assignment details. 
That's awesome! 
However, this is not included in v1.0

So to my question:

To get license assignment details, I'm wondering if there is a way to get the required data without making a separate call for each user in my tenant. That would amount to thousands of API calls at a time. It seems like a waste of resources.

I have considered performing a batch `POST` request with each user I want license details for in the request body. However, I don't know if Microsoft would consider this to be one call for the initial POST request or if it would count each call in the batch against the API throttling total.

Has anyone run into this issue? If so, what was your approach to getting licensing details from the Graph API?

By the way, I just wanted to say for anyone reading this who has worked on the implementation of this API, thank you! What a great resource!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters):

> By default, only a limited set of properties are returned (`businessPhones`, `displayName`, `givenName`, `id`, `jobTitle`, `mail`, `mobilePhone`, `officeLocation`, `preferredLanguage`, `surname`, and `userPrincipalName`).
>
> To return an alternative property set, specify the desired set of user properties using the OData `$select query parameter. For example, to return`displayName`,`givenName`, and`postalCode`, add the following to your query`$select=displayName,givenName,postalCode`.
>
> Certain properties cannot be returned within a user collection. The following properties are only supported when retrieving an single user: `aboutMe`, `birthday`, `hireDate`, `interests`, `mySite`, `pastProjects`, `preferredName`, `responsibilities`, `schools`, `skills`, `mailboxSettings`.

So to get `assignedLicenses`, you need spesifically request it:

```
/v1.0/users?$select=id,userPrincipalName,assignedLicenses
```